# How to reorganize a DataFrame based on a mapper?

Tags: python, pandas

My input is a pandas DataFrame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [11, 22],
 'name': ['foo', 'bar'],
 'class': ['c1', 'c2'],
 'date': ['01/07/2023', '14/05/2023'],
 'type': ['t1', 't2'],
 'attribute': ['a1', 'a2']})

   id name class        date type attribute
0  11  foo    c1  01/07/2023   t1        a1
1  22  bar    c2  14/05/2023   t2        a2
```

.. and a mapper (a Python dictionnary) :

```
mapper = {
    "infos": ["name", "date"],
    "meta": ["class", "type", "attribute"]
}
```

And my expected output is a pandas DataFrame (`out`) :

```
   id                                  infos                                              meta
0  11  {"name": "foo", "date": "01/07/2023"}  {"class": "c1", "type": "t1", "attribute": "a1"}
1  22  {"name": "bar", "date": "14/06/2023"}  {"class": "c2", "type": "t2", "attribute": "a2"}
```

I starting doing something like below but it seems that I'm not in the right way..

```
df[mapper["infos"]].apply(lambda x: {x.name: x.tolist()})

name                  {'name': ['foo', 'bar']}
date    {'date': ['01/07/2023', '14/05/2023']}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the items of your `mapper` and combine [`to_dict('records')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
out = (df.drop(columns=[v for l in mapper.values() for v in l])
         .join(pd.DataFrame({k: df[v].to_dict('records') for k, v in mapper.items()},
                            index=df.index)
               )
       )
```

Output:

```
   id                                  infos                                              meta
0  11  {'name': 'foo', 'date': '01/07/2023'}  {'class': 'c1', 'type': 't1', 'attribute': 'a1'}
1  22  {'name': 'bar', 'date': '14/05/2023'}  {'class': 'c2', 'type': 't2', 'attribute': 'a2'}
```

Comment: I thought my question would end up in the archives but you saved me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired output, you can use the apply function along with to_dict to convert each row into the required format. Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [11, 22],
    'name': ['foo', 'bar'],
    'class': ['c1', 'c2'],
    'date': ['01/07/2023', '14/05/2023'],
    'type': ['t1', 't2'],
    'attribute': ['a1', 'a2']
})

mapper = {
    "infos": ["name", "date"],
    "meta": ["class", "type", "attribute"]
}

def row_to_dict(row):
    return row.to_dict()

# Create the "infos" column
df['infos'] = df[mapper["infos"]].apply(row_to_dict, axis=1)

# Create the "meta" column
df['meta'] = df[mapper["meta"]].apply(row_to_dict, axis=1)

# Drop the original columns used for "infos" and "meta"
df.drop(columns=mapper["infos"] + mapper["meta"], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id                                        infos                                              meta
0  11  {'name': 'foo', 'date': '01/07/2023'}  {'class': 'c1', 'type': 't1', 'attribute': 'a1'}
1  22  {'name': 'bar', 'date': '14/05/2023'}  {'class': 'c2', 'type': 't2', 'attribute': 'a2'}
```